# C# in the combobox below the if work only for the first condition and not for the second. Any Idea why?

Tags: c#, combobox

The combobox when I choose Standalone it does work correctly but after that doesn't apply the second condition (Retail). I can choose Retail but nothing change in the form. It looks that only the first IF is recognized and not the second. Any idea in how can address the code? Thanks

```
        if (comboBox1.Text=="Standalone")
        {

            this.textBox4.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox4.Enabled = false;


            this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox1.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox2.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox3.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox3.Enabled = false;


            this.textBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox6.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox7.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox8.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox8.Enabled = false;



            this.checkBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox7.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox6.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox4.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox4.Enabled = false;


            this.textBox12.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox12.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox11.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox11.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox9.Enabled = false;


            if (comboBox1.Text =="Retail")
            {                


            this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox1.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox2.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox3.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox3.Enabled = false;


            this.checkBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox9.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox6.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox7.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox8.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox8.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox9.Enabled = false;



            this.checkBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox7.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox6.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox4.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox4.Enabled = false;

            this.checkBox10.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.checkBox10.Enabled = false;




            this.textBox12.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox12.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox11.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox11.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox9.Enabled = false;

            this.textBox15.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox15.Enabled = false;


            this.textBox14.BackColor = Color.Gray;
            this.textBox14.Enabled = false;   

        }

    }
```

Comment: you're nesting the second `if`. What exactly you're trying to do? If you explain your scenario than you may get a better help.

Comment: Just if the combobox1 value is standalone do something, if the combobox1 value is retail do something, if the combobox1 value is Whole do something and so on..

Comment: Maybe I should use switch but in this case where should I put the switch? Inside  private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)?

Comment: Please don't confuse problem and solutions. Using `switch` or `if` or whatever is a possible solution, but in order to decide on it, you have to describe the problem you want to solve. As far as I see, you are not looking for a textbox where `Text == "Standalone" && Text == "Retail"`, right? Then change your code accordingly. Also, please remove unneeded code from the question. The whole `this.[...]Box.[...] = [Color or false]` isn't really needed to look at the if-problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need to know basic flow of `if` loop.
This is nested if

```
if(condition==true){
    if(condition_2==true){
        //Reaches this if both are true
    }
}
```

This is if in sequence

```
if(Condition==true){ 
    //reaches if condition is true
}
if(Condition_2==true){
    //reaches if condition 2 is true
}
```

This is else if

```
if(Condition==true){ 
    //reaches if condition is true
}
else if(Condition_2==true){
    //reaches if condition 2 is true and condition is false
}
```

I believe you need to use `else if` for your case. You can also use `switch`.

Answer (score 0):

you have put the wrong condition if (comboBox1.Text =="Retail") {} in if (comboBox1.Text=="Standalone") {}

The following code is the correct answer.

```
if (comboBox1.Text=="Standalone")
    {

        this.textBox4.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox4.Enabled = false;


        this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox1.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox2.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox3.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox3.Enabled = false;


        this.textBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox6.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox7.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox8.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox8.Enabled = false;



        this.checkBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox7.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox6.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox4.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox4.Enabled = false;


        this.textBox12.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox12.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox11.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox11.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox9.Enabled = false;

}
      else if (comboBox1.Text =="Retail")
        {                


        this.checkBox1.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox1.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox2.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox2.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox3.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox3.Enabled = false;


        this.checkBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox9.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox6.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox7.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox8.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox8.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox9.Enabled = false;



        this.checkBox7.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox7.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox6.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox6.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox4.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox4.Enabled = false;

        this.checkBox10.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.checkBox10.Enabled = false;




        this.textBox12.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox12.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox11.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox11.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox9.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox9.Enabled = false;

        this.textBox15.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox15.Enabled = false;


        this.textBox14.BackColor = Color.Gray;
        this.textBox14.Enabled = false;   

    }
```